# Enthought Installtion Issue -- Error Writing to File

Tags: python, enthought

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FShsW.png)

Enthought is showing the error in the picture when installing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to install as an administrator. If you are using the comand shell use this code:

`runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd`

To run the administrator shell. Otherwise right click the program and select Use as Administrator.

Comment: After getting access to the admin what should i do.

Comment: No admin access should be required for access to your own profile.

Comment: Managed Common Install (see my separate answer) is to "Program Files", *not* to your profile, so admin access *is* required.

Answer (score 0):

Either your system has been corrupted, or your account has been configured with unusually strict security constraints, forbidding any executables from being copied into your home directory. In the latter case, the best solution would probably be to install as a Managed Common Install, as described here: https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/205922960-Installing-Canopy-on-Windows-for-classroom-lab-use